# Forward all email for one domain to a single account or file, but deliver other domains properly

Tags: linux, postfix, domain, forwarding

I have a Linux server which uses Postfix for email.  Its on a dynamic ip so I use the "relayhost" parameter to send outgoing mail through an ssh tunnel to another server on a static ip and from there it goes out to the real world.  That's been working fine since about 1998 or so.

I'm currently developing some software for a client, and it sends email to various people in that client's organization based on information in a database.  For my initial testing, I created fake people who all had email addresses like ptomblin+client1@{mydomain}.com, which worked fine and sent all the email to me.  But now I'm working with a live database, and all the email addresses are for real people in the client's organization.  I don't particularly want to send email to those people telling them that the system access they requested has been provisioned, so I'd like a way to redirect all email to that client's domain to either my email address or to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all the mail destinated to example.com be delivered to your mail address or a file, instead of being forwarded to the server specified in relayhost :

**step 1:** Add example.com to `mydestination` in main.cf so that mail destinated to example.com is delivered locally .

**step 2:** Setup a catchall for example.com and send all email to your mail address or a file. You can for example use postfix pcre to achieve this.

*Expanded step 2*

Using postfix pcre is only one way to achieve this among many others . According [to this tutorial by garisson](https://web.archive.org/web/20120701193925/http://cdfx.penguins-on-hudson.com/2007/08/29/multiple-recipient-delimiters-in-postfix) :

1. Create a local user mylocaluser and it's mailbox or maildir
2. Create a file named aliases-pcre with content :

   ```
   /@example\\.com$/ mylocaluser
   ```

   add the following lines to main.cf (if main.cf is in /etc/postfix):

   ```
   alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
   alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases, pcre:/etc/postfix/aliases-pcre
   ```
3. Restart postfix

Now, all mail destinated to *@example.com should go to mylocaluser mailbox/maildir.

Again, this is just an example. You can use any other method that best fits your needs. I tend to use pcre a lot because it allows regexp that are a bit more complex.

---

However, the above would not work as you need virtual domain.

Here's a minimal sample configuration :

```
(main.cf)
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
local_recipient_maps = 
relayhost = myotherserver.example.com
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/aliases-pcre
virtual_alias_domains = example.com
mydestination = localhost
```

File `/etc/postfix/aliases-pcre`

```
/@example\.com$/ somelocaluser
```

Comment: Can you expand on how to do step 2, or point me to some documentation for it?

Comment: No, it's still not liking the "localpart" - I send emails to paul.tomblin@mydomain.com and it bounces them with "unknown user paul.tomblin".  Email to "ptomblin@mydomain.com" gets delivered to me, so I know the mydestination part is working.

Comment: I tested my PCRE file using `postmap -q`and it does match paul.tomblin@mydomain.com but not paul.tomblin@gmail.com, but I suspect that the domain might be already trimmed off by the time local(8) gets the address.

Comment: May i ask you he content of the pcre file?

Comment: Also, what happens exactly when email "Email to ptomblin@mydomain.com gets delivered to me" : Can you read the mail in your usual mail client or it get delivred on h postfix srver to user ptomblin?

Comment: My pcre file contains just one line: `/@clientsdomain\.com$/ ptomblin`.  When I send email to `ptomblin@clientsdomain.com` it gets delivered to my unix mailbox on the same machine, just as if I'd sent it to `ptomblin` or `ptomblin@myrealdomain.com`.  Which is why I suspect that alias processing is too late because the domain has been stripped out.

Comment: And I just verified that adding the line `/ptomblinclientsdomain/ ptomblin` and then sending email to ptomblinclientsdomain also gets delivered to ptomblin.  Which to me proves that the alias file is seeing the email without the domain name on it.

Comment: Yes good point : Got it working  using virtual. I'll update again the answer

Answer (score 2):

Ok, [Eric got me close to the right path](https://serverfault.com/a/412991/218590), but not quite there.  This is what I did:

1. In /etc/postfix/main.cf:

   ```
   virtual_alias_domains = example.com
   virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias
   ```
2. In /etc/postfix/virtual_alias

   ```
   /@example\.com/ ptomblin
   ```

One `postfix reload` later and I was away to the races.  (By the way, you don't need to do `postmap` on regular expression files, only hashs)